# How to position the GWT dialog to the bottom right corner of the browser?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

```
    int browserHeight=Window.getClientHeight();
    int browserWidth=Window.getClientWidth();
    dialog.setPopupPosition(browserWidth-dialog.getElement().getClientWidth(), browserHeight-dialog.getElement().getClientHeight());

    dialog.show();
```

The above code will make the position starts from the very last pixel of the browser (ie bottom=0), which is not what i expect. I don't like css cos browser incompatible problem.
Also there a footer in my website (height=50px) if u can make the dialog to not to lay on the footer like the following pic
[image]

so, How to position the GWT dialog to the bottom right corner of the browser?

Comment: Can you create a jsfidle document with your code, we will do the rest =)

Comment: If i where you, I will position the dialog box with a css class

Comment: it's gwt, thre no jsfiddle for gwt

Comment: Ok, So if I where you, I will put the dialog div inside the footer. So, It will always be displayed at the bottom of the page. Then, float your dialog div to the right and your are done

Comment: i want it on top of the footer. also it's a dialog box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way

```
dialogBox.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PositionCallback(){

    @Override
    public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialogBox.setPopupPosition(parentDockLayoutPanel().getOffsetWidth()-         dialogBox.getOffsetWidth(), 
parentDockLayoutPanel().getOffsetHeight() - dialogBox.getOffsetHeight()-50);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be simple if we know the exact width & height of dialogbox. We also need to to know the parentPanel / parentLayoutPanel of dialogbox

This code will work but it is not the optimum code

```
dialogBox.setWidth("300px");
dialogBox.setHeight("300px");
dialogBox.setPopupPosition(parentLayoutPanel.getOffsetWidth()-300,parentLayoutPanel.getOffsetHeight()-300-50);
```

but how to know the width + height of dialogbox dynamically is another question